# Navbar with logo to the left on Ruby On Rails and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I need to insert a logo in my navbar but everytime I try to do it the navbar extends itself downward. How can I fit my logo into the navbar avoiding this?

Here's the code:

```
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to image_tag("image.png", alt: "logo"),
        '/' %>
    <%= link_to "...", '#', id: "prov" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "example1",   '#' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "example2", '#' %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `navbar-brand` class to your link.

```
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to image_tag("image.png", alt: "logo"), '/', class: 'navbar-brand' %>
    <%= link_to "...", '#', id: "prov", class: 'navbar-brand' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

nav is a block-level element which means it takes full-width by default therefore drops down under the logo. If you want to align logo to the left and navigation next to it you can wrap your logo to a div and give it a class col-sm-2 and add class to your navigation to be col-sm-10. 
So it should look like this

```html
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <%= link_to image_tag("image.png", alt: "logo"),
        '/' %>
      <%= link_to "...", '#', id: "prov" %>
    </div>
    <nav class="col-sm-10">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "example1",   '#' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "example2", '#' %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

[See this reference on how bootstrap grid classes works](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write css for NavBar and logo size.for example,

```
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}
```